# TypeScript generic base on property value

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to have an interface where the generic type is based on the value of a property in this interface:

```
interface Book<T extends BookType> {
  type: T,
  location: Shelf<T>,
}
```

Instead of using the following to define the generic type:

```
const book: Book<BookType.Technology>;
```

I want

```
const book: Book<???>;
book.type = BookType.Technology;
```

And afterwards, `location` is "hinted" to have type `Shelf<BookType.Technology>`

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Comment: No, it isn't possible

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript doesn't really support making empty objects and then assigning properties later the way you want to do it.  Usually the workaround here is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to strongly type the empty object... but you don't want to write out the full type `Book<BookType.Technology>` yourself, so that's not a good suggestion.  You'd like type inference for the `BookType.Technology` part, but that won't work because the compiler has no idea that `type` will be `BookType.Technology` until the next line.  And type narrowing doesn't work backwards.

Best practice in TypeScript is to make a strongly-typed object in a single statement instead of adding individual properties in multiple statements.  This is a lot easier for the compiler to understand.  If that's okay, then I'd suggest using a helper function which will infer the `T` in `Book<T>` for you.  Like this:

```
const asBook = <T extends BookType>(book: Book<T>) => book;
```

When you use it:

```
asBook({
  type: BookType.Technology,
  location: ... // this is hinted as Shelf<BookType.Technology> 
})
```

the type of `location` will be hinted for you as `Shelf<BookType.Technology>` as you wanted.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEFkEMBMFNQK4AdQBcD2oDmtWgMboC2SAlgDakB2WAXAFD2xUJGgBC66A1gCoCeSeAG96oUL1j4AFlXTl0WfgBoxoACKKAzqvEBhSKi30Avo2qpYAJwBmkfPADK02ORsAeXqFgAPS1WgtDi4+QVgAPlBRcS0XNwAxdCtaCQBuU0Y4fHJIK3hCKi08Sxk5Z1cbFPK3d04eASEAOklS+UV+cPT6EFA9dDhQGytiUABHBFgi0nQqBnoLazsHYJ5Pbz9mQJXQoUjotDCU3nTxBXxDadnQao9eTozusD6BoZHIQoB3azmCotBILR1bigAC8oDWvn8WyBDQiAAoAEYhFJAzzhACUoMiSJ4XQBQLh+1Qh22sOaUlkbSUulAZwuMxSJUpN1APVQ0lIQU5oA5VEs0H+QRutRCZJalIUSnCpnRQA)