# How to narrow down a TypeScript generic type within an interface, based on a property value of this interface?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

As often with TypeScript issues, it is hard to explain what I want to do with words but the following code should help understand it.
So I have a multi-level data structure (I only kept 2 levels of depth for the example but it can have more in reality) and I have to map another data structure over some of its properties.
My use case is writing a configuration object used to build a form to create and edit this data. And for that, I would like to provide the best autocompletion possible.

As far as I went, I am able to provide autocompletion for the first level by using a generic type as an entry but I can't make it work for the deeper levels.
In the following code, you will see a workaround that makes autocompletion work but that is useless since it consists of writing the property name (without autocompletion) which is exactly what I try to avoid.

This seems like a tricky case but since TypeScript experts are able to achieve quite complex things with it, I was hoping that someone out there might have a solution.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57133251/7615922) which seems related but wasn't able to build a solution out of it for my specific use case.

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=3#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) demonstrating my will.

```js
interface Foo {
    a
    b
    c: {
        c1
        c2
    }
    d: {
        d1
        d2
    }
}

interface Bar<T> {
    name: keyof T,
    child: Bar<any> // Here I would like to pass something like T[value of name] instead of any.
}

// Problematic case:
<Bar<Foo>>{
    name: 'c', // Autocomplete works here.
    child: {
        name: '' // Autocomplete doesn't work here (should propose 'c1' or 'c2').
    }
};

// Workaround:
<Bar<Foo>>{
    name: 'c',
    child: <Bar<Foo['c']>>{ // Here I would like the type to be deduced automatically instead of having to assert it.
        name: 'c1' // Autocomplete works here too.
    }
};
```

Comment: Not exactly what you've asked, but you could provide type parameter for `name`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJz6EBGJBCAXDhYZQIx30IBMdAvnQCY1731uTAYW7t6XLrlCRYiFACE4UADwAVADTIA0sggAPSCG4BnZAGsIAT3QxkagHy16IOAFsINbRroIAFsAANrzISqpqANraALpaljZ2kTEOuFIqYSoY6FoA5Ag5Dk78hK4eNHk5WgD0VcgAggCuYOgI6G4ADoEQkMgA7uhQ5mZ+0BAAdL4BwXzMJe6eyHkMOZypANxAA

Comment: Yes, indeed, I tried something like this and got stuck at the same point because it doesn't work with deeper levels of nesting: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJz6EBGJBCAXDhYZQIx30IBMNe9XhbT33bVs0IBfOmPoATDsIKS+-SUPpixuUJFiIUAIThQAPABUANMgDSyCAA9IISQGdkAawgBPdDGRGAfLXogcAC2EDTmJnQIABbAADbSyHqGRgDa5gC6Zq4eXqkZPrhqBkkGGOhmAOQIFT4+nISBITRVFWYA9G3IAIIArmDoCOhBAA6xEJDIAO7oUM5OUdAQAHSRMfEy-MiNochVrK3IHd19A0Oj4yjTs-OLK5vRcQn1mwTbzRWHnb39gyNjE5J0BAHCAKmApjNnMgFlBlrJkBJRIUANxAA